How to make a section sticky with links react-intersection-observer
I've experimented a bit with react-intersection-observer but I'm quite new at it and doesn't seem to grasp how to make the stickyness smooth in mobile.
I have a sticky section containing a couple of links and in desktop when hovering a link an image will show. Unfortunately hovering doesn't work well in mobile so what I'm aiming for is:
When the user enters the sticky section, the section with the links should stick and be centered in the viewport for the user. When the user scrolls through the links, each link will get in view with react-intersection-observer and will show as bold so the user knows its active and as well, an image will show.
My problem is that the section is not sticking for very long therefore the links are moving when scrolling and it looks a bit weird for the user. When the user has scrolled to the last link, then the user should've come to the end of its sticky container and can proceed to scroll to the next section, but until then it should stick and the links should be centered as mentioned.
How can I make the section stick for longer and not make the links move, but still set them as active with react-intersection-observer? Or is it possible?
const StickyWrapper = styled("div")`
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    height: calc(100vh - 80px);
    background: lightblue;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;

    ${above["mobile.lg"]} {
        height: 80vh;
    }
`;

const LinksLayer = styled("div")`
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
`;

const MobileView = ({ navigationData, heading }: Props) => {
    const [activeId, setActiveId] = useState<string | null>(navigationData[0].label);

    return (
        <>
            <StickyWrapper>
                <LinksLayer>
                    {navigationData?.map(({ id, src, label }, index) => {
                        if (!src) return null;
                        return (
                            <LinkItem
                                id={id}
                                key={`${src}-${index}`}
                                label={label}
                                src={src}
                                isActive={activeId === id}
                                setActiveId={setActiveId}
                            />
                        );
                    })}
                </LinksLayer>
            </StickyWrapper>
        </>
    );
};

export default MobileView;

const LinkItem = ({ id, src, label, setActiveId, isActive }: Props) => {
    if (!src) return null;

    const [ref, inView] = useInView({
        threshold: [0],
        rootMargin: "-50% 0% -50% 0%",
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        if (inView && !isActive) {
            setActiveId(id);
        }
    }, [inView]);

    const nonActiveOpacity = 0.3;

    return (
        <LinkWrapper ref={ref}>
            <CustomLink style={{ opacity: `${isActive ? 1 : nonActiveOpacity}` }}>
                <ArrowLink
                    to={src}
                    arrowHeight="30px"
                    active={isActive}
                >
                    {label}
                </ArrowLink>
            </CustomLink>
        </LinkWrapper>
    );
};

export default LinkItem;

I've tried experimenting with the height of the sticky wrapper, add fillers or triggers to the sticky section.
